# How to use event-by-event weights in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

In my data set I have for every entry (event) a weight. This weight consist of several quantities but basically represent how important this event for the data and must be accounted for.

How can I use this weights when training in Tensorflow? I don't want to simply use this as another feature.

Thanks

Comment: This is actually very specific, given a problem, I wish to understand how to use the library in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to multiply the computed cost for each example by its weight, before computing the overall cost for a mini-batch.

Let's say you have the following:

```
# Vector of features per example.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, num_features])

# Scalar weight per example.
x_weights = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size])

# Vector of outputs per example.
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, num_outputs])

# ...
logits = ...

# Insert appropriate cost function here.
cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, y)
```

The computed `cost` tensor is a vector of length `batch_size`. You can simply perform an element-wise multiplication with `x_weights` to get a weighted cost.

```
overall_cost = tf.mul(cost, x_weights) / batch_size
```

Finally you can use `overall_cost` as the value to minimize in your [optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#optimizers).